# Configure lighttpd to decompress gzip request from the client

Tags: javascript, http, compression, gzip, lighttpd

We've been using gzip to compress HTTP responses from lighttpd server using mod_deflate.  Browser handles HTTP responses itself so the JavaScript client receives decompressed response. It works just fine.

As we develop network devices, sometimes very low throughput is available, so **we would like to gzip body of larger HTTP requests** to speed it up (e.g. when uploading 10 MB firmware over network with very low upload speed).

In our JavaScript client, I am compressing body of the HTTP request like this:

```
if (apiCall.body) {
      const gZippedBody = pako.gzip(JSON.stringify({ ...apiCall.body }));
      apiCall.headers = {
        ...apiCall.headers,
        'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
        'Content-Length': gZippedBody.byteLength,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      };
      apiCall.body = gZippedBody;
}
```

This part should be correct but I haven't found a way to set lighttpd to decompress those requests, neither in the documentation nor on the Internet. **Does anybody know how to do enable decompression on lighttpd server to be able to accept gzipped request?** Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

lighttpd can accept a request body which is compressed.  More precisely, lighttpd is generally agnostic to the contents of the request body.  (An exception to this is lighttpd mod_webdav.)

What is receiving the request body on your server?  A CGI script?  A PHP application?  **YOUR APPLICATION** should check for Content-Encoding and handle the compressed request body.

Comment: I know that I can implement this in the application. But I was just wondering when there is mod_deflate that can automatically compress outgoing responses without modifying application code that there could be something to automatically decompress incoming requests.

Comment: There could be, but there isn't in lighttpd.  How should the client know that it can upload compressed content?  The app developer who writes the javascript should know if the application target accepting the HTTP request is going to be able to handle compressed content.  In most cases, lighttpd does not care about the request body content-encoding, and should not have to.  The application receiving the request body should handle request body content-encoding.

Comment: Put another way, why shouldn't your app handle content-encoding?  Why should lighttpd remove the content-encoding?  If lighttpd can remove the content-encoding, **when** should lighttpd remove the content-encoding and when should lighttpd not remove the content-encoding?  lighttpd can not know per-se the right answer to that question, which is why the app developer receiving the request body should prefer to handle content-encoding.